# Retrieval of only integer values from mixed characters array

Tags: javascript, arrays, automation

I am getting an error "Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined" when trying to retrieve only numerical values from the below array. Although i see the output being given properly but i get this error and the code fails.

```
 var array=['~ 9    view passages','~ 17    view passages','~ 1    view passages','~ 3    view passages','~ 4    view passages','~ 1    view passages'];
    for (var i=0;i<=array.length;i++){
    var Arraystring=array[i].toString();
    var temp1 = Arraystring.replace("    view passages","");
    var temp2 = temp1.replace("~","");
    var temp3=parseInt(temp2);
    console.log("String converted Array "+Arraystring);
    console.log("Stripped Array "+temp2);
    console.log("Integer Array "+temp3);
    }
```

Error:
Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Comment: use for (var i=0;i<array.length;i++)

Comment: possibly your array length is not necessarily 11

Comment: Please remove equality and write strictly : for (var i=0;i<array.length;i++)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `< array.length` instead of `<= array.length`.

Currently you're parsing out of bounds values, so it cannot call the `toString()` function.

Try this way

```
var array = ['~ 9    view passages', '~ 17    view passages', '~ 1    view passages', '~ 3    view passages', '~ 4    view passages', '~ 1    view passages'];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var Arraystring = array[i].toString();
    var temp1 = Arraystring.replace("    view passages", "");
    var temp2 = temp1.replace("~", "");
    var temp3 = parseInt(temp2);
    console.log("String converted Array " + Arraystring);
    console.log("Stripped Array " + temp2);
    console.log("Integer Array " + temp3);
}
```

Comment: Not really any different answer than the guy who gave the comment

Answer (score 1):

Your array contains only 5 elements.

But you are trying to read elements up to 10, hence your error even though script works properly.

Modified your script to read till the array length.

```js
var array = ['~ 9    view passages', '~ 17    view passages', '~ 1    view passages', '~ 3    view passages', '~ 4    view passages', '~ 1    view passages'];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var Arraystring = array[i].toString();
  var temp1 = Arraystring.replace("    view passages", "");
  var temp2 = temp1.replace("~", "");
  var temp3 = parseInt(temp2);
  console.log("String converted Array " + Arraystring);
  console.log("Stripped Array " + temp2);
  console.log("Integer Array " + temp3);
}
```